# Nim: Find index of element in seq based on predicate

Tags: seq, nim-lang

If I have a sequence of values, how would I find the index of an element based on a predicate function? For example, if I had the following seq:

```
let values = @["pie", "cake", "ice cream"]
```

How would I find the index of the first element with four characters? I know of `find`, but it seems to only find index by equality, and does not allow passing a predicate. I could implement this myself but it feels as if it should be be in the standard library if `find` is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use `map` from `sequtils` to map the predicate over the input sequence, and then to use `find` to get the index of the first `true` value in the result. This returns -1 when no element of the sequence satisfies the predicate:

```
import sequtils

proc isLen4(s: string): bool =
  len(s) == 4

echo map(@["pie", "cake", "ice cream"], isLen4).find(true)  #--> 1
```

This works, but is bad for large sequences since `map` processes the entire sequence. Thus even when the first element satisfies the predicate the entire sequence is processed. It would be better to just write a `findIf` procedure that returns the current index when the predicate is satisfied instead of continuing to process the rest of the input:

```
proc findIf[T](s: seq[T], pred: proc(x: T): bool): int =
  result = -1  # return -1 if no items satisfy the predicate
  for i, x in s:
    if pred(x):
      result = i
      break

echo @["pie", "cake", "ice cream"].findIf(isLen4)  #--> 1
```

Comment: I had ended up implementing my own procedure similar to yours. I am a bit curious if there's a reason this isn't part of the std, but implementing my own solution works just as well.

Comment: I don't know why it isn't in the Nim standard library; it isn't uncommon for languages to leave this sort of functionality up to users or third-party libraries. It is easy enough to implement, and I would guess that this is just one of a thousand simple functions that were determined to be marginally useful and left out. You could always ask [on the Nim forum](https://forum.nim-lang.org/).

Comment: Having to implement yourself such basic functions makes the language very inconsistent to me. As in every codebase the implementation might differ. Big pain